# Can I report my math GPA instead of major (CS and math) GPA when applying to graduate school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gpa

So I'm a combined Math/CS major wanting to do grad school for pure math. My GPA my first 3 semesters was terrible, and I got my shit together after that.

While I have all A's in math courses, my major GPA would include CS courses as well, and those are my worst grades. I estimate I can't raise it above 3.5 by next December.

I would like to know if I have any flexibility in how I report my GPA, i.e. if I can report a math GPA instead of a major GPA.

Comment: See [How do you get a bad transcript past Ph.D. admissions?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-do-you-get-a-bad-transcript-past-ph-d-admissions) and [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly)

Comment: Regarding GPA cutoff, see [Is the minimum GPA required for Graduate school a cut-off criteria or a general guideline?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26813/is-the-minimum-gpa-required-for-graduate-school-a-cut-off-criteria-or-a-general) and [Do all universities have a minimum required GPA for graduate school application?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15784/do-all-universities-have-a-minimum-required-gpa-for-graduate-school-application)

Comment: Regarding recovering from a poor first year, see [Is there other way to get into more advanced study of math, with a low GPA?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10086/is-there-other-way-to-get-into-more-advanced-study-of-math-with-a-low-gpa) and [Bad first year marks?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5757/bad-first-year-marks)

Comment: Thresholds are hard to determine. Check out grad cafe and get an idea of the GPA of the accepted students.

Answer (score 1):

Report the GPA they ask for. Anything else is basically fraud.

If you're unclear what GPA they require, look up their requirements, and contact them if necessary to ask. They may allow you to do your major GPA, or they may require your overall GPA. They may allow just your Math GPA.

At some point they're going to see your whole transcript, so there's no way to "hide" your past. But, many applications have a section for you to explain extenuating circumstances, where you could explain that you had difficulty with the CS materials and excelled at math.

Comment: ah, ok. i'm mostly concerned that a low enough GPA on the first page might mean only a cursory glance.

Comment: @PhillipHarris Yes, and if you fudge your GPA, they'll take a closer look  see you've fudged your GPA, and reject you.

Comment: at no point did I intend to "fudge" anything. Rather I don't know what a typical grad school application system looks like or what precise requirements they have for such things. please don't be so uncharitable.